# Dynamically update the search string in url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, url

I have a search bar in my page. On entering the search query, I am navigating the search result to other page like this **https://localhost:3000/details/?search=searchQuery**
On the other page it performs the search. Now the problem is: in the other page say component2, that also have search bar. I can search for the results in that page also. But when I am entering new search string i want my url also to get update with the new search query!
**https://localhost:3000/details?search=searchQuery** to  **https://localhost:3000/details?search=newSearchQuery**.
Can anyone help me how to do that. I am not sure what I am missing in my code!

```
onSearch(searchStr) {
  if (searchStr) {
  //  perform search
  }
  if (this.props.history) {
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/details',
      search: `?search=${searchStr}`,
    })   
  }
}
<Search
  onKeyPress={(event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      this.onSearch(event.target.value);
    }
  }}
  type="text"
/>;
```

on click of enter, the method will navigate me to newPage with the search result

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try updating the location.href?

```
onSearch(searchStr) {
  if (searchStr) {
  //  perform search
  }
    // Get the current URL and parameters as a URL object
    let url = new URL(location.href);
    // Set the parameter
    url.searchParams.set('search', searchStr);
    // reset the url
    location.href = url.toString(); // Edit to add .toString()
}
<Search
  onKeyPress={(event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      this.onSearch(event.target.value);
    }
  }}
  type="text"
/>;
```